# How to chain api calls using rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular13, rxjs7

I understand that there are lot of questions on the title's subject but I wasn't able to find clear and concise question/response that would help me with following.

Assume we have x amount of web api calls that return observables Observable<cs[]>...
See

```
  init() {
    this.service.serviceA().subscribe({
      next: (as) => {
        this.as = as;
        this.service.serviceB().subscribe({
          next: (bs) => {
            this.bs = bs;
            this.service.serviceC().subscribe({
              next: (cs) => {
                this.cs = cs;
                this.restructureABCs();
              },
              error: (e) => this.notification.showError('Failed to load cs! Error: ' + e.messageerror)
            });
          },
          error: (e) => this.notification.showError('Failed to load bs! Error: ' + e.messageerror)
        });
      },
      error: (e) => this.notification.showError('Failed to load as! Error: ' + e.messageerror)
    })
  }
```

Function **restructureABCs()** depends on  as/bs & cs.
as, bs & cs don't depend on each other.
Current implementation is ugly and can be improved but I'm not sure which operator I should use. It doesn't make sense to me to use concatMap as (according to my possibly flawed understanding) multiple streams are going to be merged into one, which I don't want.
All I need is to make sure that as/bs & cs are loaded before **restructureABCs()** function is invoked.

Angular13, rxjs7.4

Comment: nested subscriptions are considered as anti-pattern. All logic should be done using `pipe` and operators. Use `switchMap` for current case: `callA.pipe(switchMap(aResult => callB), switchMap(bResult => callC)).subscribe(cResult => .... )`

Comment: You may find [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting

Answer (score 2):

If BS, CS, AS don't depend on each other, they can run parallel, all you need is make sure all of this Observables complete to run restructureABCs(). So you can use combineLatest/forkJoin for this case.

```
combineLatest([
   this.service.serviceA().pipe(catchError(er => ...)),
   this.service.serviceB().pipe(catchError(er => ...)),
   this.service.serviceC().pipe(catchError(er => ...))
]).subscribe(response => {
      this.as = response[0];
      this.bs = response[1];
      this.cs = response[2];

      restructureABCs()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I come up with using **forkJoin**.

```
as : Array<as>;
bs : Array<bs>;
cs : Array<cs>;
as$: Observable<as[]> = this.service.serviceA();
bs$: Observable<bs[]> = this.service.serviceB();
cs$: Observable<cs[]> = this.service.serviceC();

init() {


forkJoin([
      this.as$.pipe(catchError(er => of({errMsg: 'Failed to load as! Error: ', error: er}))),
      this.bs$.pipe(catchError(er => of({errMsg: 'Failed to load bs! Error: ', error: er}))),
      this.cs$.pipe(catchError(er => of({errMsg: 'Failed to load cs! Error: ', error: er})))
    ])
      .subscribe({
        next: ([a, b, c]) => {
          this.as = a as Array<as>;
          this.bs = b as Array<bs>;
          this.cs = c as Array<cs>;
          this.restructureABCs();
        },
        error: (e) => this.notification.showError(e.errMsg)
      });
}
```

Found [helpful article about handling errors in forkjoin](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-error-handling-with-forkjoin-3d4027df70fc):